# Bower Post Install EACCES Spawn Error of NPM Packages

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

When I run `$ bower i --allow-root`, I get an "Error: spawn EACCES". I cannot figure out the where and why of it. Any help to what I have wrong is appreciated.

Within the `.bowerrc`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
      "postinstall": "./.bower-postinstall.sh"
  }
}
```

The `.bower-postinstall.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd _op && sudo npm i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set `$ chmod +x .bower-postinstall.sh` so the file can be executable.